# Mac OS Creating PDF's weirdly large in size since I changed my iPhone

Tags: macbook-pro, pdf, preview, heic

I have recently bought an iPhone SE and switched to HEIC format for the pictures. I am sending the files to my Mac (Early 2015 Pro, Mojave) with AirDrop. Even though the sizes of images are just shy of 3 megabytes, the "Create PDF" function under "Quick Actions" is creating ~15MB per page PDFs which is kinda painful in quick upload situations. How can I resolve this enlargement issue of Preview creating PDFs?

Thank you beforehand!
Cheers,
~bio

Answer (score 2):

The Create PDF Quick Action (or similar Automator actions) don't have any 'controls' for the way the PDF is created, (of the kind you find in Acrobat or the PDF Export dialog of some apps). It just 'wraps' the image data in a PDF format. *(I think it may also stick the image on your default printer page size.)*

It's possible that the HEIC format, being newer, contains compression that the PDF format can't use, so it has to use a less efficient method. How large (pixels) are the images?

It's certainly possible to resample the image data, or increase the compression used, of a PDF: you could create a new Quick Action to create the PDF and then downsample or compress it.

What's the purpose of converting them to PDF? Are you collating images together into one file?

There are other (dare I say better) Quick Actions for PDF manipulation, including one to Create a PDF from images, which is faster than Apple's own and preserves the images' dimensions.
https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite

Comment: I am going to check the software out. It is my assumption as well, maybe it is because I am using an outdated OS on my Mac (purely for sound engineering purposes). I am a junior student in Mechanical Engineering creation of PDF's from images is the choice of my department.

Comment: I have installed the quick actions workflow and run it with the same files, it appears to be the same.

Comment: Okay, here is my solution, which is not really cool but works for simple handwritten text documents. I have created a automation workflow which converts heic to jpeg and to pdf. After that it applies reduce size of file quartz filter which outputs really small but usable file. I am going to keep the question open if there is more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF file usually stores an image as a separate object (an XObject) which contains the raw binary data for the image.

This is not generally an image in the sense of a TIFF or a JPEG – it is the binary data for the pixels, the colorspace used for the image and additional information.

The actual pixel data can be compressed and one of the compression formats (DCTDecode) is the same used as in a JPEG. If you save this data, it can be opened as a JPEG file, but it may need altering to include the colorspace data.

Depending on the tool used to create the PDF your HEIC file is “converted” and included in the PDF generated.

And depending on the parameters used when creating said PDF no compression might be used - besides the obvious, that is that HEIC is much more efficient for file size than the compression algorithms currently supported by Adobe’s PDF (assuming you want to keep the pixel dimensions and dpi of you original images when included). So you might end up with a large file size for your PDF.

PDF is not a good image storage format. Why not use JPEG, TIFF or PNG?

EDIT: if you have a folder of HEIC files on your Mac, launch the terminal (Zsh) and create JPEG copies of your HEIC using sips:

```
for i in *.heic(:r) ; sips -s format jpeg "$i.heic" --out "$i.jpg"
```

Comment: I need to used PDF as it is the department choice for turning in assignments and exams. My major is not really mac friendly (Mechanical Engineering) so lecturers are usually forgetting the fact that one might use Mac OS as daily driver. Do you know any way that I can directly transfer jpeg, png or whatever format via AirDrop. We only have 5 minutes to turn in any given exam and I don't really want to increase my process steps from picture to PDF.